# WPF and RibbonControlsLibrary throws a BindingExpression path error without even using Bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, ribboncontrolslibrary

I have a question regarding WPF and RibbonControlsLibrary. I tried to find the source of this error myself but I just do not seem to be able to find it.

I am using the [WPF RibbonControlsLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx) from Microsoft. When using the RibbonToggleButton I get the following error even without any bindings in my XAML code.

```
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary">
    <r:Ribbon>
        <r:RibbonTab Header="Admin" >
            <r:RibbonMenuButton/>
        </r:RibbonTab>
    </r:Ribbon>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'IsChecked' property not found on 'object' ''RibbonMenuButton'
>   (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsChecked;
>   DataItem='RibbonMenuButton' (Name=''); target element is
>   'RibbonToggleButton' (Name='PART_ToggleButton'); target property is
>   'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

I am a bit confused by the last part of the error: `target element is RibbonToggleButton (Name='PART_ToggleButton'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object').` There is no RibbonToggleButton in my XAML code at all?

Did someone else see such a behavior and is able to point me into the right direction to get rid of this error output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see that error in the VS output for any ribbontogglebutton.  I have attempted to resolve it, but with no luck.  Unfortunately, the only fix I have come up with is that it's one of those errors you can ignore.

Comment: It should only appear in the VS Console unless you set up a logger for it.

Comment: Is this still not fixed after 8 years?

Comment: I have no idea, but it appears to still be a popular question.

Comment: I just reported it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/665487/potentially-spurious-warning-ischecked-property-no.html

Comment: Which was moved to https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1473

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [RibbonMenuButton class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonmenubutton.aspx) on MSDN I see that it uses PART_ToggleButton as a TemplatePart attribute. [This article](http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-part-names) describes how TemplateParts work. Since it's baked into the control it's probably expected behavior.

**Update:**

Looks like the WPF team has been notified of the problem in the comments [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/10/21/wpf-ribbon-october-2010-update-details.aspx). Perhaps it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: That article titled "WPF Ribbon October 2010 Update Details" has no comments anymore...